# Is this a coupled system of PDEs?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, boundary-value-problem, parabolic-pde

I came across this question

[Set of coupled partial differential equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1653992/set-of-coupled-partial-differential-equations)

And the answer is clear. However, what if the solution of the second equation does not appear in the first equation for example
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=a$$
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}=b$$
Would this still be considered a coupled system?

Also, in the theory of PDEs, we usually derive weak formulations. Say for example we have a system of two equations posed on a domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t} + L(u,v) = f,
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial t} + P(v) = g,
\end{equation}
\begin{align}
\text{Plus Boundary and Initial conditions.}
\end{align}

Where $u$ and $v$ are the unknowns, $f$ and $g$ are given data, and $L$ and $P$ are two differential operators.

How would you tackle such a problem to obtain a weak formulation and the existence and uniqueness of a solution?

**My thought** is to treat the second equation separately and prove the existence and uniqueness of $v$. Then, treat the first equation to find $u$ assuming $v$ is given. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your thoughts are correct, as the solution $v$ of the second PDE can be derived without any knowledge on $u$. When this is done, you can solve the first PDE to get the solution $u$, which then of course depends on $v$.
But note that this only works, if there is no extra dependence in the boundary conditions.

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful.